# XCode: The file “[APP NAME].app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file

Tags: objective-c, xcode

For context, I am encountering this immediately after resolving this issue:

[Xcode error: unable to create directory '/[PATH_TO_APP]/[APP_NAME].app' (in target '[TARGET]' from project '[PROJECT]')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62685737/xcode-error-unable-to-create-directory-path-to-app-app-name-app-in-targ)

Here is the full error details text (with redactions in [] for privacy):

```
Details

The file “[APP NAME].app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
Domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain
Code: 260
Failure Reason: The file doesn’t exist.
User Info: {
    NSFilePath = "/[APP NAME].app";
}
--
The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 2
Failure Reason: No such file or directory
--


System Information

macOS Version 10.15.5 (Build 19F101)
Xcode 11.5 (16139)
```

Running ls -l in the project folder shows the [APP NAME].app now present, but navigating to the same location and selecting the file in Finder shows a "crossed out circle" over the app's icon. Removing the file and building again results in the same thing. I've also tried renaming the project and restarting, etc, to no avail.

Comment: The `NSFilePath` is weird looking `/[APP NAME].app` - Xcode is looking for your app in the root. You sure you didn't make a mistake while redacting the error message? What's the `ls -ld [APP NAME].app` output in the project folder?

Comment: Just double checked, the error message above is accurate. That would make sense; Xcode wouldn't find the .app if its looking in the wrong folder. Is this controlled or affected by a build setting or something. Maybe something I changed by mistake. `ls -ld [APP NAME].app` outputs `drwxr-xr-x  205 [ME]  staff  6560 Jul  2 12:14 [APP NAME].app`

Comment: 205 links and 6560 bytes? This is at least very suspicious.

Comment: I would expect 3 links - what's inside? `ls -la [APP NAME].app` (omit `-d`, add `-a`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSFilePath = "/[APP NAME].app"` feels like a missing or misspelled environment variable.

If the build expects custom environment variable like `$(MyBuildDir)` to be defined, when it's not, then running a command with `$(MyBuildDir)/[APP NAME].app` would result in `"/[APP NAME].app"`

The same is true for if the environment variable misspelled. For example, using `$(UBILD_DIR)/[APP NAME].app` instead of `BUILD_DIR` would result in `"/[APP NAME].app"`